# Dllimport functions work on other machine

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

i create C# application which have simple function to open and close tray. So i start to call DllImport inside my win7 computer which have settings of framework 4.5 and that work well, but problem appears when those folder try to run on other computer, it want run, why?

Am I missing something?

Well functions like MessageBox run on any of other machine but want run functions which i call from DllImport.

Here is code from Form which want run on another machine:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA")]
public static extern int msciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);

private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    msciSendString("set CDAudio door open", "", 127, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Comment: Please read on how to ask a proper question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  If you want someone to take time out of their busy day to help you, please show some effort.

Comment: Why? ... try compile this project on win7 and run on another version of windows and see if it work http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9396/Open-and-Close-CD-drive-in-C

Comment: Which function are you importing?

Comment: @TCS [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA")]

Comment: Which error do you receive?
Use "mciGetErrorString()" to get error string, or use "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757153(v=vs.85).aspx" to get the error define.

Comment: i don't get any error, function on other machine just want work (cd drive want open) but function like MessageBox work as well

Comment: What is the return value?

Comment: int  .... public static extern int msciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);

Comment: And I'm trying to understand, it doesn't work when you run on other computers, but it does on yours???

Comment: yes on my is working ... like on link whic i put in above comment ... it work on my computer but want in virutal machine ... which have installed everything like i have ...

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work because you don't have the CD drive attached to the virtual machine?

Comment: @JimMischel Good consideration, finally that was an issues. Thnx man